# How to implement Lightbox for MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, lightbox

I'm trying to implement lightbox in my MVC solution. I've downloaded the package from NuGet repository and I'm not able to get this running in my solution.

I've added in the BundleConfig this code:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/lightbox").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/lightbox-2.6.min.js"));
```

In _layout.cshtml I've added the line:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lightbox")
```

Then, in a view that I want to show lightbox I have added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#gallery a").lightBox();
});
```

And finally, I've added these lines to show lightbox in my image gallery:

```
<div id="gallery">
@foreach (var image in Model.Images)
{
    <a href="@Url.Content(ViewBag.Path + image.filename)">
        <img src="@Url.Action("Thumbnail", "Ad", new { width = 150, height = 150, filename = @image.filename})" alt="@image.filename" />
    </a>
}
</div>
```

But with these lines I can't show images with lightbox. They are opened in the browser as a normal image.

Any suggestion about this issue would be appreciated.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: does you have any errors in browser's console?

Comment: The error I get isUncaught TypeError: $(...).lightBox is not a function

Comment: show please how you render bundle in the html. Seems like your library is not referenced in html

Comment: In _layout.cshtml I put: 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lightbox")

Comment: Can you please put your layout code here? Also check whether is jquery loaded before this library

Comment: In _layout.cshtml I have:
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lightbox")

Comment: to help you I need to see layout and html pages. If you prefer, we can discuss it in the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81959/discussion-between-simoco-and-levimatt).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `min.js`
You can't wrap a `min` version of scripts in bundle of MVC.

Because its already minified.

Try instead-

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/lightbox").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/lightbox-2.6.js"));
```

Comment: Now the javascript error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @Levimatt, Please check if you've done the same for jquery in bundles. If not then try swapping the order or jquery.

Comment: If I put the line in _layout.cshtml @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") just in the head tag of the _layout.cshtml, I get the error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).lightBox is not a function

Comment: can you please put the lines of code of injecting scripts into the view?

Comment: I inject the scripts in layout.cshtml not in the view

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#gallery a").lightBox();
});
</script>
```

And then transform de anchor link in this way:

```
<a href="@Url.Content(ViewBag.Path + image.filename)" data-lightbox="image">
```

Comment: Check the spelling. Seems like instead `$(..).lightBox()` it should be `$(..).lightbox()`